# Confusion with i++ and i=i+1

Tags: c, operators

Please do help me with explaining the output of my code. Currently I'm an amateur in C. If `i++` and `i=i+1` are the same things then why such difference in output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int i=0;
printf("%d %d %d \n",i++,i,i++);
int j=0;
printf("%d %d %d \n",j=j+1,j,j=j+1);
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 2 0
2 2 2

Process returned 7 (0x7)   execution time : 0.081 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the logic behind your output, you need to have an idea of Pointer and how it works.

The C language exhibits an undefined behavior (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) where you can't predict the way the syntax will work on the execution.

i++ -> increments i, but returns the previous value of i.
++i-> increments i, and returns the new value of i after assignment.
i = i + 1 -> adds 1 to i, writes it to i, and then returns the new value of i after assignment.

Refer this link for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Based on this principle, the output can be analyzed as below.

```
int i=0;
printf("%d %d %d \n",i++,i,i++);
```

Firstly, i=0
it starts execution from the right side i++ 
First, it assigns the value& the pointer stores 0; then the increment will take place. So, i=1.

In the next step, there is only a variable. So, the pointer doesn't store the value; it only stores the address. Therefore, i=1.

Last step execution is the same as the first step. So, i=2.

Now, it will print the stored value. So, the output is 1 2 0.

Now, let's analyze the second OUTPUT.

In the second output, the expression is j=j+1.
So, first, it executes all the steps and then prints the value.
So, the second output is 2 2 2.

I hope you now got the difference between i++ & i=i+1.